# Adding graphs, pie charts, bar diagrams in geoexplorer?

Tags: graph, geoexplorer

Does any one know how to add interactive graphs in Geoexplorer as shown in this video ?

Do we have to incorporate Google fusion tables ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9ADUHGUXL0